# Hg push a new branch to remote

Tags: mercurial, push

how to push a branch to remote not merge with default in hg ?

Comment: You can use `hg push --force`

Comment: @ecm: I don't think that's what the OP is getting at, but it is admittedly extremely unclear what the OP really wants to know.

Comment: @torek Yeah, I interpreted that as referring to the case where a `hg push` command replies like this: pushing to ... \
searching for changes \
remote has heads on branch 'default' that are not known locally: ... \
abort: push creates new remote head ...
(pull and merge or see 'hg help push' for details about pushing new heads)

Comment: Or just use a topic branch together with a non-publishing server-repo (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/tutorials/topic-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you created *new named branch* locally and want to push this branch's changesets to some remote (with possible any other data), you have, definitely, re-read *carefully* [`hg help push`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/push) and discover option

```
--new-branch    allow pushing a new branch
```